# typescript set type depending on value

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes in an optional `variant` and a `value`. If the variant is `multi` the user needs to use a tuple, otherwise a number. Is there any way to type this dynamically? Conceptually it should work like this:

```js
interface SomeInterface{
  variant?: 'single' | 'multi'
  // pseudocode
  value: variant === 'multi' ? [number,number] : number
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type SomeInterface = {
    variant?: 'single'
    value: number
} | {
    variant: 'multi',
    value: [number,number]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgSQHbAgJwGYEMDG0AvFAN4CwAUFDVAG66YCWu6A-AFxQDkAzk6gDmAGwjcqtermEBXCF1QyEAIyxUAvlAA+ZCbQbNWwLtwQzhwJtwA0emg1nyoAbUUqs1t6swBdDVCoqAylHAFFMTC54JDQMHAJiMigAemSoLAi7KUN0EzMLK1tqfWk5LgBGDSDGELlwzAAmKMQUdCw8QigSUhS0jMwsgxZcnn4hURtB0qdncusoBr9KTQDKasxaiHqAZmaYtvjO7t70iIHi+2muWfnF-1XAymCHOQB5AGs91riOxJ6pnLGHj5SyTC6ba5zKDlJbqdabD5NWAtWLtBJdJIA4ZAvgCERiIqSF5OSrLGjw4kfXbI-Y-dHHKaOCr3IA)